# how to create a unique sequence of letter and numbers in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, field, content-length, bluej

I have a field call details which holds different sequence of letter and numbers, what i am trying to do is a Constructor that have a unique sequence of letter and numbers of length 8.

Comment: please add more details, there is no clarity in your question.

Comment: Currently, your question is very vague, and is unanswerable. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) showing what is your problem, and the context where you are using it.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some pieces of code maybe to clarify what the problem.

Comment: details have unique sequence of letter and numbers of length 8.

Comment: @MohamedGhassar do you mean your constructor should accept an argument called details ??